# When I click on completed textview I am getting resouce leak. A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: android

> I am getting resource leak problem can someone tell me whats wrong with my code. I have been finding this from hours nothing helps to solve it.
>   I have written this code in adapter class.

```
completed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String serverURL = PathUrls.pathUrl + "evs_updatedeliverystatus.php?db=" + companyName.getString("companyName", "") + "&invoiceid=" + dlb.getInvoiceNo() + "&deliverystatus=3&time=noneed";
            Log.d("completed order URL", serverURL);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(serverURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("badOrder", response.toString());
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        VolleyLog.v("badOrder", response.toString());
                        try {
                            int status = response.getInt("status");
                            if (status == 1) {
                                Log.d("Update BadOrderList ", response.toString());
                                deliveryListBeans.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(ct, "Order is completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (status == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(ct, "Order Not completed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    VolleyLog.e("Error in completing order:%n %s ", error);
                    Toast.makeText(ct, "NetworkError Not Responding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);

        }
    });
```

> I am getting following error

```
 A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
   java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
   at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:170)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:190)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
```

**VolleySingleton Class**

```
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton sInstance=null;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
 private VolleySingleton()
 {
    mRequestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext());
 }
public static VolleySingleton getsInstance()
{
    if (sInstance==null)
    {
        sInstance=new VolleySingleton();

    }
    return sInstance;
}
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
{
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

}

I am using volleySingleton class.

Comment: post your   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection. class also

Comment: @Anonymous I am using volley singleton class

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this one in your on response

```
finally
 {
   response.body().close();
 }
```

Comment: What is `body()` method? I am not getting `body()` after response.

Comment: are you using sqlite anywhere?